# How can I create a list inside a list with a foreach in c# ?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, lambda

In other words I need all the elements of list "**Categories**" to be the "Parent" and elements of list "**commodities**" be the children.

Example

```
public string GetCommodities()
    {
        List<dynamic> categories = new List<dynamic>();
        List<dynamic> commodities = new List<dynamic>();

        foreach (var comcat in QuickQuoteRepo.CommodityCategories.All().OrderBy(o => o.Order))
        {
            categories.Add(new
            {
                comcat.Category,
            });
            foreach (var com in comcat.Commodities.OrderBy(o => o.Name))
            {
                commodities.Add(new
                {
                    com.Name,
                });
            }
        }
        var response = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(commodities);

        return response;
    }
```

And see if it's possible to all commodities names inside each category, within this foreach.

I tried adding  a dynamic list such as:

```
dynamic listOfElements = new { CAT = categories, COMM = commodities };
```

But it does't return elemnts as parents or dependency of categories. Is the same as adding

```
commodities.Add(new
                {
                   comcat.Category,
                    com.Name,
                });
```

Comment: Are you sorting the commodities into categories? Or do you just want every category to have a list it's associated with with all commodities?

Comment: Is defining a new class to hold results an option?

Comment: This method I have is sorting commodities by category name. But I also need, every category to be associated to all its commodities.

Comment: Creating a new class is involves changing my model, and it might get messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public string GetCommodities()
{
    List<dynamic> categoryCommodityList = new List<dynamic>();
    foreach (var comcat in QuickQuoteRepo.CommodityCategories.All().OrderBy(o => o.Order))
    {
        var allCommodities = comcat.Commodities.OrderBy(o => o.Name).Select(com => com.Name).ToList();
        categoryCommodityList.Add(new { Catagory = comcat.Category, Items = allCommodities } );
    }
    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(categoryCommodityList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You class structure does not support parent-child relationships. I mean, if what you want is that each Category holds a list of commodities, then you would need something like this:

```
var result = from c in comcat 

             select new { Category = c, Commoddities = c.Commoddities};
```

This will return a hierarchy of Categories including all Commodities underneath it.

If you are just receiving a flat data set, then you need something like this:

```
var result = from c in comcat 
             select new { Category = c, 
                          Commoddities = c.Where(x=>x.Category.Name == c.Name).Select(x=>x.Commodity) };
```

Hopefully you get the idea...